# How to transform the several loops code of finding combination into recursive method?

Tags: c++, combinations, backtracking

I am trying to convert this code into recursive method

```
for(int i=0;i<25;++i)
  for(int j=i+1;j<25;++j)
    for(int k=j+1;k<25;++k)
      for(int l=k+1;l<25;++l)
        for(int m=l+1;m<25;++m)
       {//}
```

the method is finding the 25c5 combinations. In recursive way I have written this

```
int soln[5];
void backtrack(int c)
{
if(c<5)
{
    for(int i=c;i<25;++i)
    {
        soln[c] = i;
        backtrack(c+1);

    }
}
else
{ // }
```

my soln is clearly wrong cause the number of recursion is 6 million but the actual should be 50 thousand. How do I correct that?

Comment: Please add tags for language you are using C/ C++/ some other

Comment: Can you convert for three nested loop correctly, if yes then four nested loop **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void backtrack(int start, int depth) {
  if (depth < 5) {
    for (int i = start; i < 25; ++i) {
      backtrack(i + 1, depth + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Seems like it would do the same as your nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that better are nested loops than recursive way, when we compare the performance. In recursive way method has to be invoked and this takes some time.